# Verifying private constructor is not invoked/called using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, jmockit

I have the following class.

```
public Task {

    public static Task getInstance(String taskName) {
        return new Task(taskName);
    }

    private Task(String taskName) {
        this.taskName = taskName;
    }
}
```

I am testing the `Task.getInstance()` using JMockit. While I test, I need to verify that the call to the `private Task()` was actually made. I have used the `Verifications` block earlier to verify the method execution on the test fixture object, but here I don't have that.

Comment: So basically you are trying to test to see if the compiler is working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done, although it very likely *shouldn't* be on any properly written test:

```
@Test
public void badTestWhichVerifiesPrivateConstructorIsCalled()
{
    new Expectations(Task.class) {{ // partially mocks `Task`
        // Records an expectation on a private constructor:
        newInstance(Task.class, "name");
    }};

    Task task = Task.getInstance("name");

    assertNotNull(task);
}

@Test
public void goodTestWhichVerifiesTheNameOfANewTask()
{
    String taskName = "name";

    Task task = Task.getInstance(taskName);

    assertNotNull(task);
    assertEquals(taskName, task.getName());
}

@Test
public void goodTestWhichVerifiesANewTaskIsCreatedEverytime()
{
    Task task1 = Task.getInstance("name1");
    Task task2 = Task.getInstance("name2");

    assertNotNull(task1);
    assertNotNull(task2);
    assertNotSame(task1, task2);
}
```

Again, both partial mocking and the mocking of private methods/constructors should be avoided in general.

Comment: Thanks. Just a quick question along the same lines. Verifications are used to verify the method calls. Doesn't they should be verified in unit testing? I mean if you testing method makes calls to other methods, verifying the same that they were actually invoked, is it not a good practice?

Comment: Only if the method you are verifying belongs to a *separate* unit than the one you are unit testing. The purpose of mocking in unit testing is to allow a unit to be tested *in isolation* from other units it depends on. And, generally speaking, each unit is a class/type with a clear purpose.

Comment: what if getInstance() doesn't return anything, suppose a method you needs to test need verifying it called a constructor?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should be normally be testing invocations of private methods.

What matters is that your inputs give the right outputs. I would normally expect the tests to be black box. i.e. you can change the implementation but the component will still give the right output given the same inputs.

If you test such things as private methods then your tests will be very sensitive to refactorings, and their function as *regression* tests will be limited, since you'll have to refactor the tests along with your main code refactorings.

Comment: I agree to that. But just out of curiosity, is it possible or not? I believe it should be, but just don't know the way.